# Interleaving multiple TensorFlow datasets together

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

The current TensorFlow dataset interleave functionality is basically a interleaved flat-map taking as input a single dataset. Given the current API, what's the best way to interleave multiple datasets together? Say they have already been constructed and I have a list of them. I want to produce elements from them alternatively and I want to support lists with more than 2 datasets (i.e., stacked zips and interleaves would be pretty ugly).

Thanks! :)

@mrry might be able to help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See also:

- [`tf.data.Dataset.choose_from_datasets`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#choose_from_datasets), which performs deterministic dataset interleaving.
- [`tf.data.Dataset.sample_from_datasets`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#sample_from_datasets), which can be useful even though performs random sampling.

---

Even though this is not "clean", it is the only workaround I came up with.

```
datasets = [tf.data.Dataset...]

def concat_datasets(datasets):
    ds0 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(datasets[0])
    for ds1 in datasets[1:]:
        ds0 = ds0.concatenate(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(ds1))
    return ds0

ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip(tuple(datasets)).flat_map(
    lambda *args: concat_datasets(args)
)
```

Comment: I'm quite sure this won't work: `ds0 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(datasets[0])` -- shouldn't the argument be a tensor, not a `Dataset`?

Comment: I am pretty sure it works. `concatenate` is function of `tf.data.Dataset`, not of a tensor.

Comment: Thanks! That indeed works. @mikkola the reason this works is because the argument of `concat_datasets` (i.e., `datasets`) is  not a tuple of datasets, but rather a tuple of elements from the original datasets, zipped together. The argument name is a bit confusing in that sense.

Comment: I came also to this solution. However, how long does it take in your case, to concatenate multiple (>25) datasets? For me, it takes hours..

Comment: What do you mean by it takes hours? What takes that long? Iteration over the datasets?

Answer (score 2):

Expanding user2781994 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49069420/1047543) (with edits), here is how I implemented it:

```
import tensorflow as tf

ds11 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1,2,3])
ds12 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([4,5,6])
ds13 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([7,8,9])
all_choices_ds = [ds11, ds12, ds13]

choice_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(len(all_choices_ds)).repeat()
ds14 = tf.contrib.data.choose_from_datasets(all_choices_ds, choice_dataset)

# alternatively:
# ds14 = tf.contrib.data.sample_from_datasets(all_choices_ds)

iterator = ds14.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    while True:
        try:
            value=sess.run(next_element)
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            break
        print(value)
```

The output is:

```
1
4
7
2
5
8
3
6
9
```

Answer (score 2):

In Tensorflow 2.0

```
tot_imm_dataset1 = 105
tot_imm_dataset2 = 55
e = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.cast([1,0,1],tf.int64)).repeat(int(tot_imm_dataset1/2)) 
f=tf.data.Dataset.range(1).repeat(int(tot_imm_dataset2-tot_imm_dataset1/2))
choice=e.concatenate(f)
datasets=[dataset2,dataset1]
dataset_rgb_compl__con_patch= tf.data.experimental.choose_from_datasets(datasets, choice)
```

That works for me

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is

1. create a dataset (the super dataset) with files
2. interleave each files (the sub datasets): load and wrap with from_tensor_slice
3. batch it

```
    import glob

    batch_size = 32
    files = glob.glob('datasets/*.npy')
    
    def read_npy_file(file_path):
      return np.load(file_path.numpy().decode())
    
    def create_dataset(files):
      dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(files)
      dataset = dataset.interleave(
        lambda x: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
          tf.py_function(read_npy_file, [x], tf.float32)
        ),
        cycle_length=len(files),
        num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE
      )
      dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
      return dataset
    
    dataset = create_dataset(files)
    
    for batch in dataset:
      print(batch.shape)
```

The tricky part is to use tf.py_function to wrap read_npy_file, otherwise the arg passed in is a Tensor, which doesn't have numpy() function.