# TensorFlow - Interleave multiple indipently preprocessed TFRecord files

Tags: python, tensorflow, parsing, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have multiple `TFRecord` files from the Waymo Dataset, each containing consecutive points that are not consecutive across files. I'm building an input pipeline that preprocesses data for time series prediction via the `window()` API but I need to avoid the window to span accross multiple files.

To do so, I believe I should preprocess each file indipentently and interleave the final datasets.
Here's my attempt:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from waymo_open_dataset import dataset_pb2 as open_dataset #for parsing Waymo frames

filenames = [os.path.join(DATASET_DIR, f) for f in os.listdir(DATASET_DIR)]
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames, compression_type='')

def interleave_fn(filename):
    ds = filename.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(_parse_data, [x], [tf.float32]*N_FEATURES,), 
                          num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE) 
    ds = ds.map(_concatenate_tensors).map(_set_x_shape)
    ds = build_x_dataset(ds)
    return ds

def _parse_data(data):
    # Parse feature from Waymo dataset  
    frame = open_dataset.Frame()
    frame.ParseFromString(bytearray(data.numpy()))   
    av_v_x = frame.images[0].velocity.v_x 
    av_v_y = frame.images[0].velocity.v_y 
    return av_v_x, av_v_y

def _concatenate_tensors(*x):
    #Concatenate tensor tuple in a single tensor
    return tf.stack((x))

def _set_x_shape(x):
    #Set X dataset shape. If not UNDEFINED RANK ValueError
    x.set_shape((N_FEATURES,))
    return x
    
def build_x_dataset(ds_x, window = WINDOW):
    # Extract sequences for time series prediction training
    # Selects a sliding window of WINDOW samples, shifting by 1 sample at a time
    ds_x = ds_x.window(size = window, shift = 1, drop_remainder = True)
    
    # Each element of `ds_x` is a nested dataset containing WINDOWconsecutive examples 
    ds_x = ds_x.map(lambda d: tf.data.experimental.get_single_element(d.batch(window))) 
    return ds_x

dataset = dataset.interleave(interleave_fn, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

This returns

```
AttributeError: in user code:

    /tmp/xpython_26752/494049692.py:118 interleave_fn  *
        ds = filename.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(_parse_data, [x], [tf.float32]*N_FEATURES,),

    AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'map'
```

which makes sense because `print(filename)` in `interleave_fn` gives

```
Tensor("args_0:0", shape=(), dtype=string)
```

I thought the `interleave_fn` would be applied to each `TFRecordDataset`, so `filename` would be a dataset itself instead of a tensor. What's wrong here? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by looping over all TFRecord files and appending the corresponding datasets to a dataset list. Then, following this [tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49058913/interleaving-multiple-tensorflow-datasets-together) to interleave all the preprocessed datasets.